# Mother exists as a human brain within a "box" that interacts with a teenager(?) or young adult-offspring fighting for rights

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

In the 1990s I read a sci-fi novel, a one-off book (not a series). 
It began describing a futuristic time where people either have 
brain-augmentation or senior citizens have the option to discard their 
human body for a brain-box (the human brain is placed within a "box") 
to continue existing & interacting with the outside world.
Maybe both augmentation AND brain-box were included in the story??

Anyhow, after the brain of "Ger" re-connects she starts to interact 
with her offspring 
(a teenager I think or a young adult, possibly a gal or e-fem male).

I only remember that the teenager/young adult has a huge adventure trying to escape 
their fate AND not lose contact with Ger's box (brain-box) 
AND hold their allies together as a search for the father is conducted.

I believe that the father has connections with a political figure (female??)...
who bore a step-sister (is 8-12 yrs now)?

In the end the political figure (step-mother??) of the teenager/young adult is confronted. 
A duel to the death is ensues, yet one of the teenager's allies becomes champion-of the teenager/young adult... winning the fight, and succumbing to lethal wounds.

The rich step-sister becomes an ally of the teenager/young adult.

Comment: Great description. Can you remember any of the character names or dialogue?

Comment: nope... I was just reading about Psychohistorical Crisis by Donald Kingsbury (another post from someone)... so, my focus is off.

The big event I remember is a female young adult, ally to the Main character steps up as their champion in hand-to-hand duel. The description in the book includes her street-wise combat moves vs. the opponent's well-practiced knives (with a deadly poison).

Comment: I read a different question (via another user) that discussed:
https://bit.ly/2uPjMqM ... 
@Lorendiac I was curious if the story: Psychohistorical Crisis by Donald Kingsbury has a fight/duel to the death 
(between a female political figure, Eron's step-mother 
& a female ally of Eron, [Eron's champion] a street urchin)? 
The champion wins, yet dies due to her lethal wounds.